# How to match/catch certain term in URL via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, optimization, friendly-url

I want to make my CMS work like this, if you would write certain command anywhere in the pages hierarchy, the .htaccess would catch it and act on it. So for example: `example.com/admin/=pages` + `@logout` = it would logout. Currently, I only know how to do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^@logout  index.php?logout=1 [L]

# or

RewriteRule ^\=(.+)@logout index.php?page=$1&action=0&object=0&logout=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So my question is, how to make this more dynamic? Maybe, detect command following `@` and `$_GET` it as `&command=$..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^@logout  index.php?logout=1 [L]
            ^---anchors pattern to start of string
```

if you remove the anchor, and simply have

```
RewriteRule @logout  index.php?logout=1 [L]
```

the pattern will trigger if `@logout` appears ANYWHERE in the URI.